# Artisan Migrate refused by machine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I try to run the following command:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

> But I got the following error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [220] no
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

I am using laravel 5.4.16, phpadmin path is http://localhost:88/phpmyadmin
and .env files contents below

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:bFUq5MLO9KoptHFMGczqxdluMDt1dQIMn54qUjzX2OU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:88
DB_PORT=80
DB_DATABASE=angulara
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=melody

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong configuration:

```
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT = 3306
```

Comment: Now i am getting the error PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Current connection is DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=88
DB_DATABASE=angulara
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=melody

Comment: did you tried to connect with `DB_PORT = 80` ? If your http requests port is set to 88 it doesn't mean that the database connection is too

Comment: Try the 3306 port.. not 80 or 88